# Appending grabbed frames from multiple video files into list of lists

Tags: python, list, opencv

I am trying to appending a list with list of frames read from multiple video files. I have three video files,using VideoCapture class i am reading all the three files in a loop and trying to insert the read to a list. Finally I want a list of lists of frames read from the files.
for example:

frames from file1.avi:[1,2,3,4,5,6]

frames from file2.avi:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

frames from file3.avi: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

I want the output as:[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]

I am getting the output as [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

below is my code

```
videoList=glob.glob(r'C:\Users\chaitanya\Desktop\Thesis\*.avi')

indices=[]

for path in videoList:

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)


   while(cap.isOpened()):

      ret,frame=cap.read()

      if not ret:
          break
      indices.append(cap.get(1))
  cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the output as:[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]

You only have one list `indices=[]`. If you want a "list of lists of frames" you should extend your code by a second list in the for loop:

```py
videoList=glob.glob(r'C:\Users\chaitanya\Desktop\Thesis\*.avi')
videoindices = []

for path in videoList:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

    #second List
    indices = [] 

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret,frame=cap.read()

        if not ret:
            break
        # append the frames to the secound list
        indices.append(cap.get(1)) 
    cap.release()

    # append the list of frames to the list
    videoindices.append(indices)

print(videoindices)
```

The code is untested. I will test it later and extend my answer by the `print(videoindices)` output.